# Facebook take snapshot : fileNotFoundException with graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, filenotfoundexception

I can't send a picture to Facebook via Unity, I correctly connect to facebook with FB.Init in Awake and FB.Login, then I take and send the picture with the code from the documentation, but then I get this error :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

with this code :

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot() 
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        var width = Screen.width;
        var height = Screen.height;
        var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        // Read screen contents into the texture
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();
        byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

        var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
        wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");

        FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, picCallback, wwwForm);
    }
```

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An old question. But answerless, so here's how I solved the issue in my game.

There are 2 things that need to be checked/fixed to resolve this issue:

1. First of all, check on the facebook developer account if the **package identifier is matching** with the one in your unity project (this solved my problem).
2. Also, check if you the have **right key hash entered** on the facebook developer account, corresponding to the keystore being used to sign your apk.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. and i found some hint but still on testing and not confirmed.

it seems about the new facebook app policy and you have to add publish_actions submission in [ Status & Review ] of your facebook app. you can check your app setting is missing publish_actions permission which is [ This app can also : Post on your behalf ] under [ This app needs ].

**1)[ Status & Review ] > [ Start a Submission ] > click [ publish_actions ] > [ Add Items ]**

**2) click [ provide a version ] and upload application in [ Review Submission Form ]**

**3) fill in the Notes after uploaded a version**

**4) make sure [ Privacy Policy URL ] filled in [ App Details ]**

**5) upload screenshots**

**6) Submit for Review**

Take a look about the facebook new policy as below :
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/